# Getting all revisions on Wikipedia

Tags: xml, wikipedia

How to get all revisions of a wikipedia article?

I was using this link https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=US_Open_(tennis)&history=1&action=submit
It was working for some and for some it's not working like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=India&history=1&action=submit

Comment: reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Transwiki/exporting

Comment: I don't want to use wikimedia api's

Comment: What do you want to use the revisions for? Are you trying to import the article into another wiki, or are you using the data for something else?

Comment: @JackTaylor data for something else.